# "Copy string from array to array" function using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm writing a function supposed to copy a string from array to another array using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void copy_string(char *to,char *from);

void print_array(char *a);


int main(void)
{
    char *s1="Salahuddin";
    char *s2="Ashraf";

    print_array(s1);
    print_array(s2);

    copy_string(s1,s2);

    print_array(s1);
    print_array(s2);

return 0;
}

void print_array(char *a)
{
    while(*a!='\0')
        printf("%c",*a++);
    printf("\n");
}

void copy_string(char *to,char *from)
{
    while(*from != '\0')
    {
        *to++=*from++;
    }
}
```

But when running this code, it only prints the arrays once (before calling copy_string) function, and then get out of the program.

I've tried to debug it, found that when calling copy_string function the compiler goes there, checking the *from!='\0' condition and then entering the while loop, then directly goes to the end of the function.

I can't figure out what the problem is?

can any one help? thanks in advance

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this problem. -1 for not making any effort to narrow the problem down or trying something simpler first, or using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big problem here is that `s1` and `s2` points to *literal string*, and those are constant and read only. So you can't use normal pointer here.

Instead you have to use arrays, e.g.

```
char s1[] = "some string";
char s2[] = "some other string";
```

The second thing you have to do is to make sure that the destination have enough space for the source string. In the example above *it doesn't*. It can be easily solved by making the arrays fixed-size:

```
char s1[30] = "some string";
char s2[30] = "some other string";
```

Comment: yeah, it works with me now, but I have another point, a solution for this assignment in the book suggest another body for the function.. it's strange for me 
while(*to++ = *from++);
you know it worked, except that the "to" string is totally removed and changed by "from" while in my function it doesn't remove the whole string it just change the number of characters found in "from" string... now why it removed the whole "to" string in the book function, and how it deals with (*to++ = *from++) as an assignment and test in the same time?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *s1="Salahuddin";
char *s2="Ashraf";
```

With this `s1` and `s2` points to constant string not actually a character array. And their content shouldn't be changed.

Update it to

```
char s1[20] ="Salahuddin";
char s2[20] ="Ashraf";
```

Here `20` is just random number, you may want to change that.

Also in copy function, add `'\0'` at the end of the string.

```
void copy_string(char *to,char *from)
{
    while(*from != '\0')
    {
        *to++=*from++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You have to allocate sufficient storage in your destination, and you haven't, though in this case the length of the two strings happens to make it possible, BUT
2. You are modifying string literals which is Very Bad (the compiler actually stores them somewhere special, or at least can, and writing to where it stores them is not supported).

If you are ever changing the value of characters in a string, malloc() it freshly and you can do that (that also will ensure you have enough storage for it). You cant, however, say

```
char *foo = "blah";
foo[0] = 'a'; /* WRONG */
```